# Unityで大きなゲームオブジェクトを描画した際の描画速度の低下について

Tags: unity3d

Unityでアプリを開発している際に気になったので質問させてください。

シーン上での描画がカクカクしたり、低スペック端末での処理が重たくなる際のチェックポイントとしてDrawCallの回数がありますが、例えば現在シーン上で複数の画像（ゲームオブジェクト）で画面を構成している場合、不動のものに関しては一枚の背景画像（ゲームオブジェクト）にまとめてしまったほうが処理は軽くなるかと思います。
しかし、例えばその画像のサイズが大きい場合は一つしか描画しなかった場合でもシーンの描画速度に影響があるのでしょうか。
例えば、チャリ走のようなゲームを作る場合にステージを横長にした場合、横に多きサイズの画像を一つ描画し、カメラを移動するオブジェクトに合わせて移動させて、ステージを動いているようなゲームを考えており、ステージをStart時に生成しておくという場合を想定しております。

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

一般に、1枚であってもあまりに大きな画像を取り扱うと、描画速度に影響があると考えられます。メイン/VRAMともにメモリ使用量が極端に大きくなると予測されるので、それにともなう問題も想定されます。

1度に描画する範囲にあわせて分割して、表示範囲にあわせて随時ロード(表示・非常時)するといった対策をオススメしておきます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！
確かにその通りだなと思いました。

分割したほうが修正もオブジェクト単位で済むのでそうします。
ご回答ありがとうございました。